# Solving a congruence, tricky implication

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We want to prove that

$$243x \equiv 1 \mod 2018 \implies x^{403} \equiv 3 \mod 2018$$

My try :

Assume that $243x \equiv 1 \mod 2018$

We have $x^{2016} \equiv 1 \mod 2018$ (by Fermat ($1009$ is prime) and oddness of $x$) so $x^{2015} \equiv 243 \mod 2018$

but $403 \times 5 = 2015 $

hence $(x^{403})^5 \equiv 243 \mod 2018$ or equivalently $(x^{403})^5 \equiv 3^5 \mod 2018$. I wonder how to get from this last congruence to the desired $x^{403} \equiv 3 \mod 2018$ ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Hint: can you do something with the very first equation you have once you notice that $243=3^5$?

Comment: You are asking how to go _from_ $(x^{403})^{5} \equiv 3^5 \mod 2018$ to $x^{403} \equiv 3 \mod 2018$, right?

Comment: Raise $\ 3^{\large 5} x \equiv 1\ $ to power $403,\,$ then scale by $\,3\ \ $

Comment: Thanks everyone
@MarkBennet It was easy based on your comment, but I was blind :-/

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer ($x$ vs $x^k) $ which is now fixed.

Comment: I also added a remark on how it is related to computing *modular* $k$'th roots - which is very useful to know (follow the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last step of your attempt i.e. $(x^{403})^5 \equiv 3^5 \mod 2018$, you can go to the conclusion if you can show that $y^5 \equiv 243 \mod 2018$ has only one solution  mod $2018$ (because this would force $x^{403} \equiv 3 \mod 2018$ as they are both solutions).

While that statement is true, its proof is not going to be easy because it boils down to asking why $x^5 \equiv 1 \mod 2018$ has a unique solution, and this is not clear at all.

Therefore, you have not done anything wrong but got yourself in a higher power than required.

However, you did do some groundwork. For example, by noting that $243x \equiv 1 \mod 2018$, so we may raise both sides to the power $403$ :
$$
3^5x \equiv 1 \mod 2018 \implies 3^{2015}x^{403} \equiv 1 \mod 2018
$$

Now, multiply by a further $3$, and eliminate the $3^{2016}$ using an argument made in your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$3^5x\equiv1 \implies x\equiv 3^{-5} \implies x^{403} \equiv 3^{-2015} $

and $3^{2016}\equiv1\pmod{2018}$

Answer (score 1):

It's a special case of the following

**Lemma** $ $ if $\,\gcd(a,n) = 1\,$ and $\, -\color{#c00}{jk}\equiv 1\pmod{\phi(n)}\,$  then $\  a^{\large j} x\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large k}\equiv a\pmod{\!n}$

**Proof** $\ $ Raising $\, x\equiv a^{\large -j}\,$ to power $\,k\,$ yields $\,x^{\large k}\equiv a^{\large \color{#c00}{-jk}}\equiv a\,$ by $\, -\color{#c00}{jk}\equiv 1\pmod{\!\phi(n)}\ $ by [modular exponent reduction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)

**Remark** $ $  In fact  $\, x^{\large k}\equiv a\iff x\equiv a^{\large 1/k}\equiv a^{\color{}{-j}}\ $ i.e. we can easily compute $k$'th roots when $k$ is 
coprime to $\,\phi(n)\,$ by raising to power $\,1/k,\,$ just like in $\Bbb R,\,$  see [this Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242)