# Show that if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $p^n-1$ ($p-$ prime) then every element of G can be written in the form $a^p$, $a \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Show that if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $p^n-1$  ($p-$   prime) then every element of G can be written in the form $a^p$, $a \in G$

I know that if $a \in G$ then $$a^{p^n-1}=e$$ where $e $ is the unit element in $G$

$$a^{p^n}=a \Rightarrow  a^{p^{n+1}}=a^p$$
Now since $(p^n-1,p^{n+1})=1$ then $a^p$ generates the group $G$

Is this correct?

Comment: I added an answer that gives a more *conceptual* viewpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $r,s$ be coprime positive integers. Then if $G$ is finite of order (or just exponent) $r$, every element of $G$ can be written as $a^s$ with $a\in G$.

To see this, not that there are integers $u,v$ such that $ur+vs=1$.
Now given $g\in G$, we have
$$ g=g^1=g^{ur+vs}=(g^r)^u(g^v)^s=(g^v)^s$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the map $x\mapsto x^p$  is non-injective: $a^p=b^p, a\ne b$. Since $p, p^n -1$ are coprime there exist $u,v$ such that $up+v(p^n-1)=1$. Then
$a=a^{up+v(p^n-1)}=b^{up+v(p^n-1)}=b$, a contradiction. So the map is injective. Then it is surjective. QED We are using the fact that in a group of order $k$ we have $x^k=1$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 2):

*Conceptually*, by below: $\,k\!=\!p\,$ is coprime to $\color{#0a0}{f= p^n\!-\!1}\,$ so we can take $p$'th roots: $\,g = (g^{1/p})^p$.

**Theorem** $ $ [Compute $k$'th root by raising to power $\frac{1}k\!\pmod{\!f}\,$ if $\,k\,$ is coprime to $\color{#0a0}{{\rm period}\ f}$]

Suppose that $\ \color{#0a0}{a^f} = 1 = \color{#0a0}{b^f},\ $  and that $\  \color{#c00}{1/k}_f:= k^{-1}\equiv k'\pmod{\!f},\, $ so  $\, \color{#90f}{kk'} = 1 \!+\! jf.\, $ Then

$$ \bbox[10px,border:1px solid #c00]{\large a^{\large\color{#c00} k}= b \iff a = b^{\large (\color{#c00}{1/k})_{f}} }\qquad\qquad$$

**Proof** $\ (\Rightarrow)\ \ \ b = a^{\large k}\,\Rightarrow\, b^{\large k'}\! = a^{\large\color{#90f}{kk'}}\! = a^{\large 1+fj} = a(\color{#0a0}{a^{\large f}})^{\large j} = a.\ $ $(\Leftarrow)\ $ Same way $\ (a = b^{\large k'})^{\large k}$

**Remark** $ $ The proof was excerpted from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242) in an elementary number theory context (which might prove helpful as motivation). If you have good knowledge of (cyclic) groups then you may find it instructive to polish it in that language.