# For $x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$, either find a solution $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ or show that no solution exists.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find a solution $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ or show that no solution exists.
$x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$

So far I have been trying to the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve this question but I still can't figure out the answer; I'm not sure whether I used the wrong theorem or I just made some calculation mistakes. Can anyone please help me with this question?

Comment: You essentially only need to check the values $x = 0,1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Why would you use the Chinese remainder theorem for a prime modulus?

Comment: As long as you accept that square roots and fractions mean something different modulo 5 than they do in $\Bbb Z$ (well, they mean the same thing, but the concrete calculation works entirely differently), then the quadratic formula works just as well to find solutions here as it does normally. But just checking works too.

Comment: $x^2+x+1\equiv0\implies x^3=(x^2+x+1)(x-1)\equiv0$ and $x\not\equiv1,0\implies  x^9\equiv1$ and $x\not\equiv1,0\implies x\equiv1$ and $x\not\equiv1,0$, contradiction

Comment: of course I meant $x^3\color{red}{-1}=(x^2+x+1)(x-1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different way, which doesn't involve calculating five possibilities.

Assume $x^2+x+1\equiv0\bmod5$.

Then $x^3-1=(x^2+x+1)(x-1)\equiv0$ and $x\not\equiv1,0\bmod 5$.

Thus $x^9\equiv1$ and $x\not\equiv1,0\bmod 5$.

Using Fermat's little theorem, $x^4\equiv1\bmod5$, so we have $x\equiv1$ and $x\not\equiv1,0\bmod5$.

We have reached a contradiction.

Comment: Said *conceptually:* you deduce $\,x\equiv 1\,$ by raising $\,x^{\large\color{#0a0}3}\equiv 1\,$ to power $\,\color{#0a0}{1/3}\equiv 1/(-1)\equiv 3\pmod{\!\color{#c00}4},\,$ since $\,x\not\equiv 0\Rightarrow\, x^{\large \color{#c00}4}\equiv 1\,$ by Fermat, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242).

Comment: That's what I did, @BillDubuque, but thanks for the reference and explanation why

Comment: It's not at all clear what you did from what little is written - hence my comment. In particular, it's likely not clear to many readers how to generalize what you did. The prior links shows how.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x&=0,1,2,3,4\pmod5\\
x^2&=0,1,4,4,1\pmod5\\
x^2+x+1&=1,3,2,3,1\pmod5
\end{align}$$

So, no such $x$ exists.