# Prove $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $1 \leq n \leq 5$, so that $5|n^3+k$

Tags: divisibility

As the title says, I have to prove this.
Since n just ranges from 1 to 5, I wondered if it is okay to just prove it like the following?

For n=1:
$5|{1}^3+k$, when $k \in${…,-11,-6,-1,4,9,14,…}

For n=2:
$5|{2}^3+k$, when $k
\in${…,-13,-8,-3,2,7,12,…}

For n=3:
$5|{3}^3+k$, when $k
\in${…,-12,-7,-2,3,8,13,…}

For n=4:
$5|{4}^3+k$, when $k \in${…,-14,-9,-4,1,6,11,…}

For n=5:
$5|{5}^3+k$, when $k \in${…,-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,15,…}

Labeling the different sets of k as ${k}_1,{k}_2,…,{k}_5$,

we see that ${k}_1 \cup {k}_2 \cup {k}_3 \cup {k}_4 \cup {k}_5 = \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: This proof would work if you correct the congruence classes for $n=2,3$ and the union over the $k_i$ still produces $\Bbb Z$...  (Hint: those two are swapped.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @abiessu, mistyped that.

Comment: Note $\,5\mid n^3+k\iff \bmod 5\!:\ n^3\equiv -k\iff -k\,$ has a $\rm\color{#c00}{cube}$ root $\!\bmod \color{#0a0}5,\,$ which holds true by a simple [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242) proved in the dupe linked above, because  $\color{#c00}3$ is coprime to $\,\phi(\color{#0a0}5)=4.\,$ It yields for $\,a\not\equiv 0\, $ that 
$n^3 \equiv a \!\iff\! n\equiv a^3,\,$ e.g. $\,n^3\equiv 2\iff n\equiv 2^3\equiv 3.\ \ $